# Expanding and collapsing tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small tree like this (tree with many children not binary):

```
class Node {
    constructor(name) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = null;
        this.children = [];
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
}
```

I need to bring it to the page. When you click on a node you will see her children.

```
root node
      child node 1, child node 2
```

And if you press the node again, the children clean up.

```
root node
```

any simple solution in clear js and html?

Thx for all!

**UPD**
how to link classes and html? may be this solution:

```
  class Node {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];
  }

  showNode() {
    const nDiv = document.createElement("div", { id: "ndiv" });
    const newContent = document.createTextNode(this.name);
    nDiv.appendChild(newContent);

    document.body.appendChild(nDiv);
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor(root) {
    this.root = root;
  }

  show() {
    for (const child of root.children) {
      child.showNode();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear how these two classes relate to html elements

Comment: Its unclear for me too but i'm update post

Comment: So you need to break this problem down and get the display of the tree working (at some leve), before you tackle how to handle the expanstions

Comment: I'm update post